# Cant get Communication to Happen Between two nRF24L01 Modules

Tags: nrf24l01

I've been trying to get communication to work between two nRF24L01 modules, as seen in [this](https://hobbycomponents.com/2136-large_default/nrf24l01-24ghz-wireless-radio-transceiver-module.jpg) image, and I have been having nothing but trouble.

I simply want to get simplex communication to happen between the two of these modules. I think my issues are stemming from not setting up the modules correctly for receive and transmit (All of the other troubleshooting points such as: wiring, SPI waveforms etc have been methodically verified), so I am hoping that someone here will be able to help me with getting the correct procedure for setting up the modules.

For now I will skip the `RF_SETUP` and `CONFIG` registers, as I am fairly certain that they are correct and not the source of issue, and will focus on the address and data pipe setup. Lets say nRF1 is the Receiver and nRF2 is the transmitter. Their setup is as follows:

nRF2 (Receiver)

1. Listen on a Data Pipe, "Data Pipe 0",  by setting `ERX_P0` (By default, this is set at reset (along with data pipe 1), according to the datasheet, so I will not change it.).
2. Make sure that "Data Pipe 0" has a unique address at `RX_ADDR_P0` (By default, at reset, this is set to `0xE7E7E7E7E7`, so I will not change it).
3. Set the number of bytes allowed in the RX payload of "Data Pipe 0" at `RX_PW_P0` (this is zero at reset). I set this to be 1 Byte by writing a `1` to `RX_PW_P0`.

nRF1 (Transmitter)

1. Set the address of the data pipe to transmit to at `TX_ADDR` (By default, at reset, this is `0xE7E7E7E7E7`, so I will not change it.).

Am I missing anything major in this setup procedure for communication? I've been having so much trouble getting these modules to work.

Comment: what are you using to control the modules?

Comment: @jsotola an AVR.

Comment: One or two AVRs? Arduino's? Two nNRF24L01+ can't talk if they are too close together.

Comment: @tlfong01 One ATmega328P. For testing purposes, while I have been trying to get the communication happening, both of the nRF modules are on the same breadboard.

Comment: @Kalcifer, I forgot who told me that two transceivers cannot stand too close, otherwise their RF waves would interfere.  You may like to skim some of my old posts  to find more details: (1) How can Rpi communicate with Arduino in RF (Radio Frequency), Say Using nRFL2401+? (Q&A):
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108959/how-can-rpi-communicate-with-arduino-in-rf-radio-frequency-say-using-nrfl2401,

(2) How can Rpi communicate with Arduino in RF (Radio Frequency), Say Using nRFL2401+? (Chat Record):
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/103645/2020/1/24, / to continue, ...

Comment: (3) Getting a NRF24L01 module running with Java:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111679/getting-a-nrf24l01-module-running-with-java.  Cheers.